# jqGrid not displaying valid json

Tags: json, jqgrid, jsonp

After reading most of the questions and trying to find an answer, I think I give up.

So the problem I'm having is just like what other people have been having, that is, jqGrid doesn't display the valid json received from a spring mvc servlet.

Here is my json:

```
{
    "firstRecordIndex": 0,
    "pageSize": 20,
    "sortDirection": {
        "name": "descending",
        "code": 1
    },
    "sortCriterion": "id",
    "pageNumber": 1,
    "objectsPerPage": 20,
    "fullListSize": 1,
    "searchId": null,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "index": 0,
    "list": [
        {
            "issueNumber": "ABC-6799",
            "entryDate": 1345763592879,
            "billingType": "Non-Billable",
            "notes": "Hello",
            "customer": "XYZ",
            "id": 1,
            "hours": 5,
            "userName": "John Doe"
         }
    ]
}
```

An here is my jqGrid:

```
jQuery(function(){ 
  jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    url:"http://localhost:8080/worktime/timesheet.html?type=list&ajax=true",
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:["User", "Hours", "Date", "Billing Type", "Notes"],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:"userName", width:90, editable:false, jsonmap:"userName", editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10}},
      {name:"hours",  width:55, editable:true, jsonmap:"hours", editoptions:{size:10}}, 
      {name:"entryDate", width:90, editable:true, jsonmap:"entryDate", formatter:"date", "formatoptions":{"srcformat":"m/d/Y", "newformat":"m/d/Y"}, 
          editoptions:{size:12, dataInit:function(el){jQuery(el).datepicker({dateFormat:"m/d/y"});},defaultValue: "m/d/y"}
      },
      {name:"billingType", width:100, editable:true, jsonmap:"billingType", edittype:"select", editoptions:{value:"INV:Billable-Invoice;TSA:Billable-TSA;NON:Non-Billable;OH:Overhead"}},
      {name:"notes", width:150, sortable:false, editable: true, jsonmap:"notes", edittype:"textarea", editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"20"}} 
    ],
    pager: "#pager",
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    sortname: "entryDate",
    sortorder: "asc",
    jsonReader: {
    root: "list",
    total: "totalPages",
    page: "pageNumber",
    records: "fullListSize",
    repeatitems: false,
    id: "0"
    },
    caption: "Timesheet History",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
  });
```

What's the correct jqGrid configuration? I am using jqGrid 4.4.0 and jQuery 1.7.2. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have this: `id: "0"`?

Your `jsonReader` should probably be:

```
jsonReader: {
  root: "list",
  total: "totalPages",
  page: "pageNumber",
  records: "fullListSize",
  repeatitems: false,
  id: "id"
}
```

Comment: It has been more than 4 years since I asked this question and I just saw this answer. My apologies... I don't quite remember how this problem was resolved but I wish I'd seen your answer. Thanks for your response!